# error with feed excel in drupal

Tags: drupal, feed, feedparser

After installing Feeds Excel Parser and Feeds XLS, I get the error

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'sites/default/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
C:\...\sites\all\modules\feeds_xls\feeds_xls.template.inc on line 34
```

Comment: What is your question, or did you just want to let us know that you get an error?

Comment: i want fix error this.

Comment: when i try import file excel ( xls ) by feeds import, 
i get error :  path: /homeshop2/batch?id=438&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseTextt: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'sites/default/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\...\sites\all\modules\feeds_xls\FeedsExcelParser.inc on line 40
please help me fix this